# Unable to install Theia (Eclipse Theia) on an AWS EC2 t2.micro instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yarnpkg, theia, theia-ide

I have installed all the packages by following this prerequisite [guide](https://github.com/eclipse-theia/theia/blob/master/doc/Developing.md#prerequisites). However, I can't figure out what the issue is with the never-ending command below:

```
git clone https://github.com/eclipse-theia/theia \
    && cd theia \
    && yarn \
    && yarn download:plugins \
    && yarn browser build \
    && yarn browser start
Cloning into 'theia'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 125810, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (234/234), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (163/163), done.
remote: Total 125810 (delta 86), reused 191 (delta 70), pack-reused 125576
Receiving objects: 100% (125810/125810), 165.17 MiB | 23.67 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (94777/94777), done.
yarn install v1.22.21
$ node-gyp install
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@10.0.1
gyp info using node@20.10.0 | linux | x64

gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v20.10.0/node-v20.10.0-headers.tar.gz
gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v20.10.0/node-v20.10.0-headers.tar.gz
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v20.10.0/SHASUMS256.txt
gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v20.10.0/SHASUMS256.txt
gyp info ok 
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
[3/5] Fetching packages...
warning plugin-a@1.44.0: The engine "vscode" appears to be invalid.
warning plugin-b@1.44.0: The engine "vscode" appears to be invalid.
[4/5] Linking dependencies...
warning " > @theia/electron@1.44.0" has unmet peer dependency "electron@^23.2.4".
warning "workspace-aggregator-0b1c984e-4f7a-4341-92ca-1931e7a0971c > @theia/messages > react-perfect-scrollbar@1.5.8" has unmet peer dependency "react@>=16.3.3".
warning "workspace-aggregator-0b1c984e-4f7a-4341-92ca-1931e7a0971c > @theia/messages > react-perfect-scrollbar@1.5.8" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@>=16.3.3".
warning "workspace-aggregator-0b1c984e-4f7a-4341-92ca-1931e7a0971c > @theia/preview > markdown-it-anchor@5.0.2" has unmet peer dependency "markdown-it@^8.4.1".
warning "workspace-aggregator-0b1c984e-4f7a-4341-92ca-1931e7a0971c > @theia/process > node-pty@0.11.0-beta17" has incorrect peer dependency "node-gyp@^8.3.0".
warning "workspace-aggregator-0b1c984e-4f7a-4341-92ca-1931e7a0971c > @theia/scm > react-autosize-textarea@7.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0".
warning "workspace-aggregator-0b1c984e-4f7a-4341-92ca-1931e7a0971c > @theia/scm > react-autosize-textarea@7.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0".
[5/5] Building fresh packages...
[10/18] ⠂ drivelist
[11/18] ⠂ keytar
[13/18] ⠄ node-pty
[9/18] ⠄ native-keymap
[5/18] ⠄ nsfw
```

I have re-checked if all the packages are installed mentioned in pre-requisite guide.